# Coming up with a stopping condition in a helper function C++,

Tags: c++

i currently need to figure out a stopping condition for a recursive helper function that stops when there is only one number left on the list, or there are no numbers left to try.  The program is to guess the the number 1-100 and progressively correct itself in order to find out the number the person is thinking of, i have a good idea on how to get the numbers in order if the person says it's too high, too low, or if they say the program got it right. however, i do not know how to stop the function if there is only one possible number left to guess, or if the user cheated and there are no numbers left to try. here is what i have for the recursive function so far, and i really do not know where to begin on my current problem stated earlier, thanks for the help in advance :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void guessingGame(int size, int low)
{
string answer;
unsigned int median = (low + size) / 2;
cout << "Is your number " << median << " l , y , h? ";
cin >> answer;

if (answer == "l" || answer == "L")
{
    low = median;
    guessingGame(size, low);
}
if (answer == "h" || answer == "H")
{
    size = median;
    guessingGame(size, low);
}
if (answer == "y" || answer == "Y")
{
    cout << "Told ya i'd guess it!\n";
}

  while (answer != "h" && answer != "y" && answer != "l")  
{                                                             
    cout << "\nPlease enter a valid input: ";                              
    cin >> answer;                                      
    cin.clear();                                  
    cin.ignore(50, '\n');                                        
    guessingGame(size, low);                                 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, but I'll consider it as pseudo code and answer your question specifically.

Basically, your stopping condition would be when `low` is equal to `size`, and you have only one number remaining. At this point you have two options:

- The user will enter 'y', then this is the correct guess and you can return from the function.
- The user will enter 'l' or 'h'. In this case, the user is cheating since only one number is remaining and it's not the correct one.

I'd suggest moving the checking for 'y' to the beginning, before the other two checks for 'h' and 'l', then write something as the following:

```
if (answer == "y" || answer == "Y")
{
    cout << "Told ya i'd guess it!\n";
}

else if (low == size)
{
    cout << "Not fair! You're cheating.\n";
   // exit the routine.
}

else if (answer == "l" || answer == "L")
{
    low = median;
    guessingGame(size, low);
}
else if (answer == "h" || answer == "H")
{
    size = median;
    guessingGame(size, low);
}
```

If the user doesn't answer with 'y', and you have only one number left, then they're cheating.

Again, your code has problems, but this is just an idea of how the stopping condition would be.

Comment: Thanks for helping on this, also, I new it would not compile, I only include the function code itself, the project had a few other parts to it so I didn't want to include anything unnecessary,  but helps me out a ton, I was just overthinking it, and the else ifs do make more sense. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. It's indeed a good practice to include only the part related to the question and not everything. And welcome to the community.